# Magento 2 Fotorama swipe with mouse open fullscreen mode

Tags: magento2, fotorama, magento2.4

I've an issue with fotorama slider

1. Sliding fotorama slider with my mouse
2. When I mouse up for drag again the next pict => fullscreen mode is throwed

#### Preconditions

1. Checked on Magento 2.4 but this problem surely exists on previous versions

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Install a new magento project
2. Create a product with multiple pictures
3. Go on product page in front
4. Slide the product slider for few pixels
5. MouseUp, Meh -> the fullscreen is lauched

#### Expected result

1. When I release the mouse I would like it to give me the choice to scroll to the next picture
2. Not open the fullscreen mode !

#### Actual result

1. The fullscreen mode is open when I don't want to, I just want to drag the images with my mouse...

I've opened an issue on github magento2 repository : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/34112

[image]